# Can't see the contents of the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Output reaches flag2 but I can't see what is inside the HashMap. The code is:

```
public class traffic_analysis {


static HashMap<InetAddress,Integer> mp=new HashMap<InetAddress, Integer>();


    static void SrcCnt(InetAddress src_ip) {
        InetAddress SourceIP = src_ip;
        System.out.println(SourceIP);

        if (mp.get(SourceIP) == null){
            mp.put(SourceIP, 0);
            System.out.println("----MPIKE----");
        }else {
            mp.put(SourceIP,mp.get(SourceIP)+1);
            System.out.println("----MPIKE XANA----");
        }

        System.out.println(mp.toString());
    }


static void PrintMap() {
    System.out.println("----EIMAI EDW----");

    Iterator iterator = mp.keySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println("----flag----");
       String key = iterator.next().toString();
       System.out.println("----flag2----");
       String value = mp.get(key).toString();
       System.out.println("----flag3----");

       System.out.println(key + "blabla " + value);
    }
}


}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: So what happens?  Does it get to "flag3"?  Does it get to "blabla"?  Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `toString` on the actual key. When you try to get it with the *string*, that will fail. Try this instead:

```
InetAddress key = iterator.next();
System.out.println("----flag2----");
String value = mp.get(key).toString();
System.out.println("----flag3----");
```

Comment: No, the `Map.get` method takes an `Object`. (Legacy reasons iirc.)

Comment: @DHall: No, Map.get takes Object, not K. There are other questions around why that's the case :)

Comment: InetAddress key = (InetAddress) iterator.next();
System.out.println("----flag2----");
String value = mp.get(key).toString();
System.out.println("----flag3----");    Now it is ok.. TY!!

Comment: @user758084: If you declare `iterator` to be `Iterator<InetAddress>` you won't need the cast.

Answer (score 0):

The toString() method of an object doesn't do the same thing as casting the object to a String.

What about `String key = iterator.next()` rather than `String key = iterator.next().toString()` ?